# Why is my class' destructor being called when leaving the scope of a private function belonging to the class?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been refreshing myself with C++ and am trying to create a linked list class with 2 strings that has a function which will sort items in the list alphabetically. I send them to a swap function by passing pointers to the two items in the list being compared and then they trade pointer information so that the list is "reorganized", as shown here:

```
void LinkedList::swapItem(LinkedList* a, LinkedList* b)
{
LinkedList temp = *a;

a->pNext = b->pNext;

// if statement to prevent b->pNext from pointing back to b if items are 'adjecent' to eachother in the list

if(b == temp.pNext)
{
    b->pNext = a;
}
else
{
    b->pNext = temp.pNext;
}

a->idNum = b->idNum;
b->idNum = temp.idNum;
}
```

This function is called by another function which is supposed to check the values of the "last name" string and determine if they need to be swapped. Then it switches the iterators(which are the pointers that were passed in to the swap function), and is supposed to continue through the list, but after the swap function, the iterators/pointers point to the same place but the data in the objects is just gone because the destructor is called at the end of the swap function! why would it call the destructor when the objects are still being used? Is there a way to tell the destructor to stop? Here is the code for sorting alphabetically:

```
LinkedList* LinkedList::sortAlpha()
{
LinkedList *top = this;
LinkedList *pItrA = this;
LinkedList *pItrB = this->pNext;
LinkedList *temp = NULL;

while(pItrA != NULL)
{
    while(pItrB != NULL)
    {
        if(pItrA->alphaOrder > pItrB->alphaOrder)
        {
            swapItem(pItrA, pItrB);
            temp = pItrA;
            pItrA = pItrB;
            pItrB = temp;
            temp = NULL;

            if(pItrB->idNum == 0)
            {
                // Tracks the pointer at the "top" of the list if pItrB is the new top item
                top = pItrB;
            }
        }
        pItrB = pItrB->pNext;
    }
    pItrA = pItrA->pNext;
}

return top;
}
```

I know this code is probably VERY messy, or at best inefficient, but I'm not too concerned about that because I'm just trying to understand how it all works and why.

Comment: Private Destructor can be used to prevent destructor being called(assuming there is no inheritance) !

Comment: @KaustavRay : That isn't true in a member function, and it makes it rather hard to make these other than with `new`...

Comment: Your swap logic is wrong. If you want to swap node contenrs, swap just the payload and leave the links intact. That is, your swap function should not mention pNext at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand now ! As it is going out of the scope ! It can be only prevented using `new`

Comment: [OT]: you may use `std::swap` to avoid to use temp variable and avoid to do the swap manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a local temporary `LinkedList`, initialized by *copying* `a` into it:

```
LinkedList temp = *a;
```

When that temporary goes out of scope, its destructor gets called.  That is what is supposed to happen, and you can't stop it without eliminating the temporary.

You should rewrite your `swap` function so that it doesn't require making a copy of `a` in this way.  It doesn't seem like you can make your current swap function correct unless you do so.

One of two things are likely happening when you create this temporary:

1. The copy constructor does a *shallow copy*, bringing over pointers from the source.
2. The copy constructor does a *deep copy* on plain pointers, and replicates the structure.
3. You use reference-counted pointers and do something much fancier.

The shallow copy lets you test pointers directly, as you do in your swap function.  A deep copy would give you unrelated pointers between the two copies.  And #3 seems unlikely at the moment.

Then, when you destroy the temporary, a couple different things might be happening:

1. You don't `delete` anything, leading to potential memory leaks.
2. You delete the entire chain starting at the temporary, obliterating a good portion of your linked list (assuming a shallow copy).

I'm guessing since you came here, the situation looks closer to #2.

---

Including my further thoughts from below:  Your swap logic looks flawed.  To swap items in a singly linked list, you need to manipulate the `next` pointers of the *predecessors* to the swapped nodes, and you do not have those available to you in your swap function.

In this case, you're better off just swapping the other members of the class, as opposed to manipulating pointers.  If your class had a large amount of data in it, then you might be better off with pointer manipulation, but you need to know the predecessors of the two nodes you're swapping (or at least a pointer/reference to the `pNext` in the predecessors) to do it correctly.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, I think. so temp gets destroyed going out of scope, and since it contains a pointer to "b", and "b" now contains a pointer to "a", the data is all being destroyed... I think I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @ManicCure : For everyone's benefit, I added some likely explanations of what's going wrong above.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @ManicCure : BTW, how are you actually swapping two items without using the `next` pointers that point to the items themselves?  The list above looks like a singly linked list (or, at least, there's no mention of a `pPrev` or the like).  But to swap `a` and `b`, don't you need to inform their predecessors?  It _might_ be safer to just swap their contents rather than manipulate the pointers.

Comment: I ended up doing something completely different for the swap. Everything finally works the way its supposed to now. I couldn't switch the entire contents of each object since they contain the strings which are being sorted alphabetically. This exercise was meant to help me understand pointers a little better... I think it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The variable temp is being destroyed, and presumably destroying the other LinkedList objects that it points to. Instead, rewrite as:

```
void LinkedList::swapItem(LinkedList* a, LinkedList* b)
{
LinkedList* tmpNext = a->pNext;
auto tmpId = a->idNum; // I use auto because I don't know what type idNum is (int ?)

a->pNext = b->pNext;

// if statement to prevent b->pNext from pointing back to b if items are 'adjecent' to eachother in the list

if(b == tmpNext)
{
    b->pNext = a;
}
else
{
    b->pNext = tmpNext;
}

a->idNum = b->idNum;
b->idNum = tmpId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe Z was correct with

> You delete the entire chain starting at the temporary, obliterating a good portion of your linked list (assuming a shallow copy)

So I rewrote the alphaSort function to handle everything:

```
LinkedList* LinkedList::sortAlpha()
{
bool sorted = false;

LinkedList* top = this;
LinkedList* prev = NULL;
LinkedList* itr = NULL;

while(sorted == false)
{
    prev = NULL;
    itr = top;
    sorted = true;

    while(itr != NULL)
    {
        if(itr->pNext != NULL && itr->alphaOrder > itr->pNext->alphaOrder)
        {
            LinkedList *temp = itr;
            LinkedList *tempNext = itr->pNext->pNext;

            if(itr->idNum == 0)
            {
                itr->idNum = itr->pNext->idNum;
                itr->pNext->idNum = 0;
                top = itr->pNext;
            }

            itr = itr->pNext;
            itr->pNext = temp;
            itr->pNext->pNext = tempNext;
            sorted = false;

            if(prev != NULL)
            {
                prev->pNext = itr;
            }
        }

        prev = itr;
        itr = itr->pNext;
    }
}

itr = top;
int idCounter = 0;

while(itr != NULL)
{
    itr->idNum = idCounter;
    idCounter++;
    itr = itr->pNext;
}

return top;
}
```

Thanks for the input everyone!